# What are some good two factor methods for logging onto your Mac?

Tags: login, authentication

What are some options I can deploy to require users to use multi factor authentication when logging onto their Macs. In the same fashion you use your password and Google Authenticator code to log into Gmail, GitHub, Slack, etc., is there something for logging into your Mac.

Comment: It is OT here to talk about future OS updates, but 10.11.0 seems it will have this implemented.  (this is not an answer as it is not currently possible with 10.10 or lower)  [Apple Dev Support article](https://developer.apple.com/support/two-factor-authentication/)

Comment: Ah, that's pretty neat. I'll have to see if I can enable it on my El Capitan beta and see how well it works before deploying to the rest of the team. Thanks @bjbk!

Comment: Glad to help!  @Zlatty

Answer (score 1):

How about something like Knock?  http://www.knocktounlock.com
It's not exactly the same as looking up a time-dependent code, but does require the 'second factor' in order to unlock.

The neat thing is that many apps (I think Knock included) run on Bluetooth, so when you walk away from the Mac and the BT disconnects, it automatically locks up the machine.

Answer (score 1):

[SAASpass](https://www.saaspass.com/platforms/mac-osx-two-factor-authentication-one-time-password.html) provides Bluetooth proximity-based (Mavericks and up), scan-QR-on-Mac-with-iOS-device and OTP as second factor.

Answer (score -1):

A [quick Google](http://bfy.tw/12CH) gives a few viable options, but true two-factor authentication is extremely difficult to implement on a Mac. Since Apple does not provide a solution for this, a third party would need to create an app that works with either a SMS or a companion iPhone app. The only problem is Apple does not let developers make a way to prevent the person from using their computer. You could find a solution that creates a new password and sets the account password every time you sleep or log out, but it would still not be as easy and smooth as iCloud or Google two-step verification.

Comment: That search actually does not solve anything as there is a mix of web apps that support 2FA on a mac, and those are specific to logging into a Mac. Proper searches lead to apps/devices such as Sesame 2, Knock, Keycard, Rohos Logon Key, and YubiKey.